# Automatically export new emails to folder?

Tags: applescript, mail.app, automator

The manual process:

1. New email arrives in inbox X (Apple Mail)
2. Drag-n-drop to Finder folder Y
3. Delete email in inbox X

How can this be done automatically using AppleScript/Automator?

Comment: Yes this can be done with applescript and launchd

Comment: Need to edit to be more clear. Do you want the mail sorted into a mail folder, or do you want it dumped as a file into a Finder folder? The former is easy, use a Smart Mail Folder filter...

Comment: The latter (Finder folder)